# How to join df on itself in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

How to join my DataFrame?

```
d = {'users': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'code': [12,21,34,12,21,40,74,40,92]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to  match my "users" using "code".

I want my table to be like this-

```
user1 user2 code active  
1      4      12   1
2      5      21   1
3     NONE    34   0
6      8      40   1
```

and so on..

Comment: is it better now? (edit a question)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do there. The table you want has 4 columns but your dataframe only has 2. How do you want to populate these extra columns? Where did the `active` column come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to create class "Pair" that would contain id1, id2, code, and status. And store a list of these objects.

But if you have to use your structure you can use a custom function to create such DataFrame.

```
    def get_data_frame(data):
        columns = ['user1', 'user2', 'code', 'active']
        main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
        for index, user in enumerate(data['users']):
            if data['code'][index] in main_df['code'].unique():
                main_df.loc[main_df['code'] == data['code'][index], ['user2']] = user
                main_df.loc[main_df['code'] == data['code'][index], ['active']] = True
            else:
                temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[user, None, data['code'][index], False]], columns=columns)
                main_df = main_df.append(temp_df,  ignore_index=True)

        return main_df
```